# How do I pass a fortran string to const char* in c++ using fortran-C binding?

Tags: c++, fortran

I need to pass a string known at compile time from fortran to a c++ library. None of the pages in my search results have involved this particular distinction. Here is what the code looks like currently:

Fortran:

```
subroutine fci_wmm_associate_variable(array_name, array_pointer)
    implicit none
    character*100, intent(in), value       :: array_name
    type (c_ptr), intent(in)        :: array_pointer
    interface
        subroutine wmm_associate_variable(name_f, pointer_f) bind (c)
            use iso_c_binding
            character (c_char), intent(in)  :: name_f
            type (c_ptr), intent(in), value :: pointer_f
        end subroutine wmm_associate_variable
    end interface
    call wmm_associate_variable(array_name, array_pointer)
end subroutine fci_wmm_associate_variable
```

C++:

```
void wmm_associate_variable(char* varname, double* var_pointer)
{
    //do stuf
}
```

This compiles fine, but my library needs the C++ function to look as follows:

```
void wmm_associate_variable(const char* varname, double* var_pointer)
{
    //do stuf
}
```

I get an undefined reference when this happens:

```
undefined reference to `wmm_associate_variable'
```

How do I make it work for a const char*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fortran-C interoperability feature works with C functions, consequently the C++ function needs to be declared with C linkage (`extern "C"`).

(Note the Fortran declaration of the C function has the first argument as a default character kind scalar with length `c_char` - what you more than likely want is for it to be a c_char kind, length one assumed size array - `character (KIND=c_char), intent(in)  :: name_f(*)` )